# what's syntax for uncheck the checkbox for in specific row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I'm new to JQuery, i want to uncheck certain row in the repeater grid.

I got this work, this will uncheck all checkbox for me.

```
$('span.chkIncRows input').attr('checked', false);
```

This works for me, if I want to uncheck row #2 checkbox from the repeater, without passing row number.

```
$('span.chkIncRows input')[2].checked =false;
```

I don't know the syntax to uncheck the checkbox, if i want to pass in the row number into checkbox.

For example: I really want to do something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
$('span.chkIncRows input')[rowNumber].checked =false;
```

Thanks advance for your help.
Annie

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$('span.chkIncRows input:eq(1)').attr('checked', true);
```

Note that it's zero-based, so `input:eq(1)` selects the second `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('span.chkIncRows input').eq(2).attr('checked', false);
```

It's hard to say without knowing exactly what your HTML looks like. [edit] Also check @SLaks' answer; it depends on the context for the operation. The selector (':eq()') is handy but it means you have to glue the string together (which admittedly is not difficult).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `eq` selector: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

`$('span.chkIncRows input:eq(1)').attr('checked', false);`